# Using egen functions with replace

Tags: replace, stata, mean

I created a new variable from the mean of another variable using `egen`:

```
egen afd_lr2 = mean(afd_lire2w) if ost == 0
```

Now I would like to replace the values with the mean of another variable if `ost == 1`:

```
replace afd_lr2 = mean(afd_lireo) if ost ==1
```

This is not possible, as the mean function cannot be used with the `replace` command.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
egen afd_lr2 = mean(cond(ost == 0, afd_lire2w, cond(ost == 1, afd_lireo, .))), by(ost)
```

Here is a test:

```
clear
input float(group y1 y2)
1 42   .
1 42   .
2  . 999
2  . 999
end

egen mean = mean(cond(group == 1, y1, cond(group == 2, y2, .))), by(group)

tabdisp group, c(mean)

----------------------
    group |       mean
----------+-----------
        1 |         42
        2 |        999
----------------------
```

The key is that the `mean()` function of `egen` feeds on an expression, which can be more complicated than a single variable name. That said, this is trickier than I would generally advise, as

```
generate work = afd_lire2w if ost == 0
replace work = afd_lireo if ost == 1
egen mean = mean(work), by(ost)
```

is easier to understand and should occur to a programmer any way.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
sysuse auto, clear

generate price2 = price + 5345

egen a_price = mean(price) if foreign == 0
egen b_price = mean(price2) if foreign == 1

replace a_price = b_price if foreign == 1
```